# Ler um objeto Json com javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Em uma requisicao ajax ele me retorna o seguinte:

```
{
 "og:locale":"pt_BR",
 "og:type":"article",
 "og:title":"Um titulo qualquer",
 "og:url":"http:\/\/www.umsite.com.br\/uma-url\/"
}
```

Minha requisicao:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",            
            url: '../pegaurl.php',
            data : { "url" : url},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (e) {  

                console.info(e[0]);
...
```

Como faço para ler cada elemento separadamente no javascript depois?

Comment: Thiago, Poderia ser mais especifico e postar sua requisição ajax ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta!

Comment: Obrigado, irei responder

Comment: Na verdade isso ai não é um *array* como o título diz, é um objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Podes iterar as chaves desse objeto com um `for ..in` ou com `Object.keys` e depois `forEach` ou `for`.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
var obj = {
  "og:locale": "pt_BR",
  "og:type": "article",
  "og:title": "Um titulo qualquer",
  "og:url": "http:\/\/www.umsite.com.br\/uma-url\/"
};

for (var chave in obj) {
var detalhes = [chave, chave.split(':')[1], obj[chave]].join(' > ');
  console.log(detalhes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar " Atributos " do retorno ajax é simples, você só precisa colocar uma variável no parenteses `( json )` do método utilizado, e acessar com `.nomeAtributo`. 
Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: dados,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json){
        if (json.status) {
          console.log("success");
          $("#cadastrar").each(function() {
            this.reset();
          });

          iziToast.success({
            title: 'Ok',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"
          });

        } else {
          console.log("error");
          iziToast.error({
            title: 'Erro',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"
          });

        }
      },
      error: function(json){
        iziToast.error({
          title: 'Erro',
          message: "Erro ao fazer requisição",
          icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"
        });
      }
    });
```

Está é uma requisição ajax, e o meu ajax retorna um json com um status e uma mensagem `status/message`, para acessar esses atributos, eu uso `json.status/json.message`.

No seu caso seria `e.locale` ou `e.org:locale`

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar o problema do  [`:`] podemos fazer um `.replace`
global do string e recuperar para o nome simple :

```
var string = '{"og:locale":"pt_BR","og:type":"article","og:title":"Um titulo qualquer","og:url":"http:\/\/www.umsite.com.br\/uma-url\/"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(string.replace(/og:/g,""));

console.log(obj.locale);
console.log(obj.type);
console.log(obj.title);
console.log(obj.url);
```